# Cannot pass values back to base class/Boolean is always returning false

Tags: java

I was struggling a bit on this sub class that is for a project. My constructor needs to call the minPassingAvg variable back to the base class (kid) but keep getting a compiler error of (cannot convert to string) which isn't even my intention, and is used as a condition for a boolean that I use below which always returns false. At this point I'm not sure what is needed or unnecessary in my current code.

```
    import java.util.List;

    public class MonitoredKid extends Kid{

      public int minPassingAvg;

      public MonitoredKid(int minPassingAvg) {

         super(minPassingAvg);

      }


      public void setMinPassingAvg() {

         this.minPassingAvg = minPassingAvg;

      }

     public int getMinPassingAvg(){  
          return minPassingAvg;
       }


      public boolean isInTimeOut() {

         if(getAverageScore() >= minPassingAvg ) // If kid's average test scores
                                                 // are above minimum average he 
                                                 //   is not in time out
            {
            System.out.print("no");
            return true;
            }

            else{
             System.out.print("yes");

            return false;
            }

           }

       }

============================
        public Kid()
   {  
      name = "";
      totalScore = 0;
      testCount = 0;
   }



   public Kid(String n)
   {  
      name = n;
      totalScore = 0;
      testCount = 0;
   }


      public double getAverageScore()
       {  
          return totalScore / testCount;
       }

       public double getTotalScore()
       {  
          return totalScore;
       } 

       public void addTest(int score)
       {  
          if(score >= 0 && score <= 100)
          {
             totalScore = totalScore + score;
             testCount= testCount+ 1;
          }
          else
          {
            System.out.println("Scores must be between 0 and 100");

          }
}
===========================
     import java.util.Scanner;

 public class MonitoredKidTest
    {  
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {  
          Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

          int avgNum = 0;

          System.out.print("Enter the minimum passing average: ");
          avgNum = keyboard.nextInt();

          Monitoredkid kid2= new Monitoredkid(avgNum);

         kid2.isOffProbation(avgNum);
```

Comment: Are you ever setting it? Passing it into the constructor, and then calling your (un-needed set method)

Comment: First your setter method is missing a parameter, you are self assigning in this case, your setter should be as follows `public void setMinPassingAvg(int minPassingAvg ) { his.minPassingAvg = minPassingAvg; }` 
second it would be helpful to show the getAverageScore() method so we can review.

Comment: @Zeyad added the following methods of the other class for more insight

Comment: @Intruder1500CC can you also post the constructor of the Kid class and show the field that it includes, i suspect that your Kid class constructor is adding the value to a field of data type String not an int.

Comment: @Zeyad added for you

Comment: @Intruder1500CC i gave you my answer down below because it is more clearer than using the comments when we want to put lines of code, please check it

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing an error because your base class `Kid` has a constructor with String parameter and you are calling it with integer from `MonitoredKid`

To fix this,You can create a constructor in parent class `Kid` which accepts integer as an argument.

You can also fix this by changing parameter type to either class and make it consistent or by performing type casting. I would say converting an `Integer` parameter to `String` is better if parent class is being used by other sub classes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Kid class constructor if it is accepting integer as input. If not then you need to create a constructor which accept integer as input. Also paste the exact error and stack trace for others to understand your problem well.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem here is that the constructor of the Kid class accepts a String parameter and you call it using super but then you pass it an int instead. I understand that name is a String so you might need to make another constructor or change the existing Kid constructor that accepts the String if you don't need it.
For your application to work you will need to have an int field in your Kid class, then a constructor that will initialize it, you are free to make a totally new constructor or remove an existing one, depending on your requirements, as below:

```
public class Kid {

    public int minPassingAvg;

    public Kid(int minPassingAvg) {
        this.minPassingAvg = minPassingAvg
    }

}
```

by then in your MonitoredKid class, you will have your regular constructor as follows

```
public class MonitoredKid extends Kid{

      public int minPassingAvg;

      public MonitoredKid(int minPassingAvg) {

         super(minPassingAvg);

      }
}
```

so you see in this case you won't get an error, because when you use the keyword super, it means call the constructor of the parent class, so now you are calling the constructor and passing it an int, which was what you were already doing, but in the Kid class your constructor was expecting a string not an int because you typed in the arguments "String name" so it was trying to convert the int to String, but now it is expecting an int and you are sending it an int.

Comment: thank you, works. But my boolean isOffProbation() always returns false no matter the value. I've been looking around my program to see if there's any input errors and I cannot identify what is messing up my boolean. the AverageScore method is quite simple and I called it to the same class as the boolean from the base class, but always will return as false. Any thoughts? it seems that minPassingAvg when it reaches if(getAverageScore() > minPassingAvg) doesn't evn hold a value.

Comment: it looks normal, this depends on the values you give, so do you put the values in the program manually or you capture them from the user, in either case, it would be helpful to post it

Comment: It takes user input,however I am unsure if I have conflicting methods that change it to zero or something else. Added the 3rd class with the coding. I currently get this complier error MonitoredKidTester.java:24: error: method isOffProbation in class MonitoredKid cannot be applied to given types;
      kid2.isOffProbation(avgNum);
              ^
  required: no arguments
  found: int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: i don't see your isOffProbation() method declaration so i can't judge, you just added the method call